# Thermo energy. How does it work and how can i do it!? :D

Tags: heat, generator, thermal, conductivity

I see youtube videos where people use heat from their hands and other places on metal to create energy. But most of the time there's a cold side. How does all this work and how could i make a simple one.

Ps. I also saw an invention where you plug your phone into a coffe mug and the heat from the coffee charges it!

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware - there is no such thing as free energy - you extract power from your hot coffee and your coffee gets colder. Is that what you want - cold coffee?

Comment: this is probably better asked is the "physics" questuon site,  it's really a thermodynamics question.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is probably Peltier.

Comment: Most of the heat loss from a mug of coffee is from evaporative cooling (that's why a cover is so effective). The amount that would go through the bottom is very low. You could replace the bottom of the mug with a copper or aluminum slug to get more efficiency but the coffee would get cold very fast and there might be other problems. But Peltiers (thermopiles) are what you want- if you run them in reverse there is a small amount of power available at the terminals when heat is flowing through them (hot to cold side). There are also Stirling Engines which may be better in some situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All** of the time there's a cold side. You cannot extract energy from the heat energy in a hot body alone. You can only extract energy from the flow of heat between a hot body and a cold one.

The efficiency of getting work from a temperature difference depends on the size of difference. With a large difference, good efficiency is possible, but it's still possible to do worse than that by using a lousy method or lousy materials. 100% efficiency is only theoretically possible when the cold side is at absolute zero.

Coffee mugs, hands, the breeze past the cold heatsink, these sorts of hot and cold sources work best with a Peltier device, and give efficiencies down in the 1% ballpark.